# INNO setup - CreateInputQueryPage after install has completed returns initial values, not the ones edited

Tags: inno-setup

I am new to INNO and getting better every but I am having a problem with the CreateInputQueryPage that is running after the install is complete. It is returning the initial values that I put in as the defaults, not the edited values the user has edited.

Here is the code that creates the page. This seems to be fine.

```
procedure InitializeWizard();
var
    ret      : boolean;
begin

  SvrSetup := CreateInputQueryPage(wpInfoAfter,
    'i2x Server setup', '',
    'Please specify your Company name, Listener host name and Port. then click Next.');
  SvrSetup.Add('Company name:', False);
  SvrSetup.Add('Listener host name:', False);
  SvrSetup.Add('Port:', False);
  SvrSetup.Values[1] := 'computer name'
  SvrSetup.Values[2] := '5551';

end;
```

I run this code on the NEXTBUTTONCLICK event to validate my input

```
function NextButtonClick(CurPageID: Integer): Boolean;
begin
    Result := true;

  { Validate certain pages before allowing the user to proceed }
  if CurPageID = SvrSetup.ID then 
    begin
      if SvrSetup.Values[0] = ''  then  begin
         MsgBox('You must enter company name.', mbError, MB_OK);
         Result := False;
      end;
      if SvrSetup.Values[1] = ''  then begin
         MsgBox('You must enter listner host.', mbError, MB_OK);
         Result := False;
      end;
      if SvrSetup.Values[2] = ''  then  begin
          MsgBox('You must enter listner port.', mbError, MB_OK);
          Result := False;
      end;
    end;

end;
```

Now when the install is over but before the final page I do this.

```
procedure CurStepChanged(CurStep: TSetupStep);
begin
  if CurStep = ssPostInstall then 
  begin
    WriteXML;       
  end;
end;
```

And WriteXML is this.

```
procedure WriteXML;
var
    FileData: String;
begin

    FileData := ''
    LoadStringFromFile(ExpandConstant('{app}\EMailer\EMailer.exe.config'), FileData);
    StringChange(FileData, '!OVERRIDE_COMP!',ExpandConstant('{code:GetEmailerCompany}'));
    SaveStringToFile(ExpandConstant('{app}\EMailer\EMailer.exe.config'), FileData, False);


end;
```

With the value I need to insert into the XML as code:GetEmailerCompanyas

```
function GetEmailerCompany(Param: String): String;
begin
  // Return the company for email
  Result := SvrSetup.Values[0];
end;
```

Aagain, It is returning the initial values that I put in as the defaults, not the edited values the user has edited. What am I missing?

Thanks

Comment: The problem is that your page is shown after `ssPostInstall` step.

Comment: Is it not possible to show pages after ssPostInstall and gather information?

Comment: It is. You are already showing a page after `ssPostInstall` step. The problem is that you are saving the information from that page too early. You may consider using the `NextButtonClick` event and save the information when your page is about to leave. Using the `NextButtonClick` event has a the benefit that you can stay on the page when saving fails for some reason. And if the user goes back to that page and modifies the information there, it will update the output file.

Comment: Aaaahhhhhh. Thanks! I see it now. I need to change ssPostInstall to ssDone. Again a BIG thanks!

Comment: You're welcome! Well yes, that's another option.